# Flutter firestore query on document array field

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I've got this firestore database.

[image]

There is a 'users' collection containing documents of users. Each user has their own information such as name and a cart. I would like to get all the 'carts' of a particular user in a stream. How would you go about with the query?

Answer (score 1):

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.Collection("users").doc("docIdHere").get().then((. 
document) {
//it will get the first item in the cart with index zero
document.get("cart")[0];
//then do what you want
});
```